# how to test for options(fields) in settings API?

Tags: php, settings-api

I've created an options page in wordpress with this code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rtwhc_add_admin_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'rtwhc_settings_init' );

function rtwhc_add_admin_menu(  ) { 
    add_menu_page( 'Welcome Home CRM API Settings', 'Welcome Home Settings', 'manage_options', 'welcomehome_contact', 'rtwhc_options_page' );
}

function rtwhc_settings_init(  ) { 

    register_setting( 'pluginPage', 'rtwhc_settings' );

    add_settings_section(
        'rtwhc_pluginPage_section', 
        __( 'WelcomeHomeSoftware.com Settings', 'welcome_home' ), 
        'rtwhc_settings_section_callback', 
        'pluginPage'
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'rtwhc_api_url', 
        __( 'The URL endpoint that you want to query', 'welcome_home' ), 
        'rtwhc_api_url_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'rtwhc_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'rtwhc_community_id', 
        __( 'Add the community ID you want to use. If you dont change it will use ID 19019 (a test community)', 'welcome_home' ), 
        'rtwhc_community_id_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'rtwhc_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'rtwhc_api_token', 
        __( 'API token from WelcomeHome', 'welcome_home' ), 
        'rtwhc_api_token_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'rtwhc_pluginPage_section' 
    );

    add_settings_field( 
        'rtwhc_debug', 
        __( 'Debug mode. Content and arrays will be added to the errorlog', 'welcome_home' ), 
        'rtwhc_debug_render', 
        'pluginPage', 
        'rtwhc_pluginPage_section' 
    );

}

function rtwhc_api_url_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'rtwhc_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='rtwhc_settings[rtwhc_api_url]' value='<?php echo $options['rtwhc_api_url']; ?>'>
    <?php

}

function rtwhc_community_id_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'rtwhc_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='rtwhc_settings[rtwhc_community_id]' value='<?php echo $options['rtwhc_community_id']; ?>'>
    <?php

}

function rtwhc_api_token_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'rtwhc_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='text' name='rtwhc_settings[rtwhc_api_token]' value='<?php echo $options['rtwhc_api_token']; ?>'>
    <?php

}

function rtwhc_debug_render(  ) { 

    $options = get_option( 'rtwhc_settings' );
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='rtwhc_settings[rtwhc_debug]' <?php checked( $options['rtwhc_debug'], 1 ); ?> value='1'>
    <?php

}

function rtwhc_settings_section_callback(  ) { 

    echo __( 'Enter your settings below.', 'welcome_home' );

}

function rtwhc_options_page(  ) { 

        ?>
        <form action='options.php' method='post'>

            <h2>Welcome Home CRM API Settings</h2>
            <p>These are the settings that you will need to make sure that Contact form 7 (you will need it installed) will send to the WelcomeHome CRM upon submission.</p>
            <?php
            settings_fields( 'pluginPage' );
            do_settings_sections( 'pluginPage' );
            submit_button();
            ?>

        </form>
        <?php

}
```

In my main php file I have set const values:
//defaults incase no options are set in the settings page.
const WHC_API_URL = 'https://amazingcrm.url';
const WHC_COMMUNITY_ID = '19';
const WHC_ENABLE_DEBUG = true;
const WHC_TOKEN = 'muchsecretverysecret';

Then I'm testing for entries based on this code:

```
function display_options() {
    $welcome_home_options = get_option('rtwhc_settings');

    if (isset($welcome_home_options['rtwhc_api_url'])) {
        $apiurl = 'apiURL is set in options: '.$welcome_home_options['rtwhc_api_url'];
    } else {
        $apiurl = 'apiURL is still from CONST: '.WHC_API_URL;
    }
    if ( isset($welcome_home_options['rtwhc_community_id'])) {
        $communityID = 'Community ID is set in options: '.$welcome_home_options['rtwhc_community_id'];
    } else {
        $communityID = 'Community ID is still from CONST: '.WHC_COMMUNITY_ID;
    }
    if (isset($welcome_home_options['rtwhc_api_token'])) {
        $apitoken = 'Our API token came from options: '.$welcome_home_options['rtwhc_api_token'];
    } else {
        $apitoken = 'Our API token came from CONST: '.WHC_TOKEN;
    }
    if (isset($welcome_home_options['rtwhc_debug'])) {
        $debug = 'Debug mode has been set by options: '.$welcome_home_options['rtwhc_debug'];
    } else {
        $debug = 'Debug Mode is from CONST: '.WHC_ENABLE_DEBUG;
    }


    $output = $apiurl.'<br>'.$communityID.'<br>'.$apitoken.'<br>'.$debug.'<br>';
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode('display-wh-options','display_options');
```

The problem that I have is when I first run the plugin without setting any content in my new options page, all data is run through the const.

However if I set values in my options page and save, then delete all the options and hit save,  the short code function to return my values ('display-wh-options') show this:

apiURL is set in options:

Community ID is set in options:

Our API token came from options:

Debug Mode is from CONST: 1

So for some reason it's return my options values of '' for the 1st three variables.  How do i set it so that if the options page fields are deleted after having had a value it still returns my default values (const)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving the options the first time `get_option( 'rtwhc_settings' )` returns `false` as the option doesn't exist.

Saving values, deleting them and then saving again causes the value of `get_option( 'rtwhc_settings' )` to be an array with the field names as keys, which have empty values.

You can see this, if you `var_dump()` the option value.

```
array(3) {
  ["rtwhc_api_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["rtwhc_community_id"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["rtwhc_api_token"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

`rtwhc_debug` is missing from the array probably, because it's a checkbox and when it's not checked it doesn't get sent with the `$_POST` data.

To fix the issue in the shortcode just replace `isset()` with `!empty()` checks. The `isset()` returns `true`, because the options array has the given key, but it doesn't care, if there's a value (as long as it's not `null`) for that key or not. With `!empty()` you check that the key exists and it has some truthy value.

My personal preference is to wrap options calls like this in a helper function, which always returns the data in the expected format and with the necessary default values.

```
function my_option_values_with_defaults(): array {
    // get options or return empty array instead of false, if option doesn't exist
    $option = get_option('rtwhc_settings', []);

    // get defaults from constants or other source
    $defaults = [
        'rtwhc_api_url' => WHC_API_URL,
        'rtwhc_community_id' => WHC_COMMUNITY_ID,
        'rtwhc_api_token' => WHC_TOKEN,
        'rtwhc_debug' => WHC_ENABLE_DEBUG,
    ];

    // mash found options and defaults together
    $parsed = [];
    foreach ($defaults as $key => $default) {
        $parsed[$key] = ! empty($option[$key]) ? $option[$key] : $default;
    }

    return $parsed;
}
```